# CefSharp screen rendering problems Windows 10 touch screen

Tags: chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I have a PiPo x9 (touch screen) running Windows 10. Google Chrome is loaded and can view the web page correctly. The same page loaded through CefBrowser responds strangely to mouse events. I am using a USB mouse and keyboard.

To demonstrate when a page is loaded it initially displays correctly.
[image]

When you move the mouse over the username textbox the screen will zoom in, however it doesn't render properly and UI elements will be unresponsive.
[image]
Another example;
[image]

I have had a look at the CefSettings here [Settings](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/), but there are too many to know what to try.

Comment: Are you using WPF with a DPI greater than 1?

Comment: @amaitland no its just winforms, and it runs on other computers without a problem.

Comment: Does it have an `Intel GPU`?

Comment: @amaitland yes it does. Intel Gen 7.

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#troubleshooting-graphics-video-or-performance-problems

Comment: Thank you very much. Your support is awesome

Answer (score 6):

I also stumbled across this problem recently. In my case it was a DPI scaling issue (my client was using an Nvidia GPU), so one way to "fix" it, is by setting the display scaling to 100% (right click on desktop -> Display Settings -> Change the size, text, apps and other items -> set to 100%).

But if you can't or don't want to do that, you can call the *SetOffScreenRenderingBestPerformanceArgs* method of CefSettings, like this:

```
var settings = new CefSettings();
//set any required settings here
settings.SetOffScreenRenderingBestPerformanceArgs();
Cef.Initialize(settings);
```